# Sum of two integral negative

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Consider $$I_1 = \int_0^{\sqrt{2}} \ln\left(\dfrac{x^6+(n+6)x^4+(5n+6)x^2+2n}{x^6+(n+6)x^4+(4n+7)x^2+(4n-2)}\right)\,\mathrm dx$$ and $$I_2 = \int_{\sqrt{2}}^{\infty} \ln\left(\dfrac{x^6+(n+5)x^4+(4n+2)x^2}{x^6+(n+5)x^4+(3n+3)x^2+(2n-2)}\right)\,\mathrm dx$$

For $n\geq 2$, while checking from interent, I am getting $I_1+I_2<0$. Is there a way how to prove it? Is it true what I am observing?

Comment: For this kind of questions, it is important to have the source of the problem, so that people are not overwhelmed by your possibly over-complicated version and more likely to find a more elegant solution. Why are you interested in this inequality? Did you encounter it when solving another problem? If so, then posting the original problem might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make it formal if we write for each term
$$x^6+ax^4+bx^2+c=(x^2-r_1)(x^2-r_2)(x^2-r_3)$$ So, expanding the logarithms, we face the summation of a series of integrals 
$$I_k=\int\log(x^2-r_k)\, dx=x \log \left(x^2-r_k\right)+2 \sqrt{r_k} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{r_k}}\right)-2 x$$
Now, it is just a matter of computing. For $n=1$, $I_1+I_2=0$ since the argument of the logarithm is equal to $1$. For $n>1$ (checked up to $n=10^5$), $(I_1+I_2)$ is always negative.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & I_1+I_2 \\
 1 & 0 \\
 2 & -0.192471 \\
 3 & -0.249089 \\
 4 & -0.273505 \\
 5 & -0.285372 \\
 6 & -0.291233 \\
 7 & -0.293868 \\
 8 & -0.294640 \\
 9 & -0.294289 \\
 10 & -0.293238 \\
 20 & -0.273526 \\
 30 & -0.255691 \\
 40 & -0.241839 \\
 50 & -0.230857 \\
 60 & -0.221902 \\
 70 & -0.214419 \\
 80 & -0.208043 \\
 90 & -0.202521 \\
 100 & -0.197677 \\
 200 & -0.168542 \\
 300 & -0.153979 \\
 400 & -0.144786 \\
 500 & -0.138286 \\
 600 & -0.133368 \\
 700 & -0.129475 \\
 800 & -0.126291 \\
 900 & -0.123623 \\
 1000 & -0.121343 \\
 2000 & -0.108641 \\
 3000 & -0.102817 \\
 4000 & -0.099288 \\
 5000 & -0.096858 \\
 6000 & -0.095044\\
 7000 & -0.093629 \\
 8000 & -0.092484 \\
 9000 & -0.091532 \\
 10000 & -0.090725
\end{array}
\right)$$
Obviously, $(I_1+I_2)$ shows a minimum value for $n=8$ and *seems* to tend to $0^-$ when $n \to \infty$.

Comment: But how to prove it?

Comment: The problem is strictly analytical since we know the analytical expressions of all the $r_k$'s as function of $n$. So, $(I_1+I_2$ is just a function of $n$ to be analyzed as any other function of a single variable.